# How to extract picture object from arrayList

Tags: vba, image, excel

I have placed a variable number of pictures inside an `ArrayList`. Each picture has its own name (through named range).

```
Dim Pic As Picture
Dim picArray As Object
Set picArray = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
For Each Pic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
    picName = differentNameEachTime
    If Pic.Left = Range(picName).Left And Pic.Top = Range(picName).Top Then
        picArray.Add Pic
    end if
next Pic
```

The above definitely works as verified by the `Msgbox` calls below:

```
Range("G3").Select
x = 0
For Each Pic In picArray
    Set picObject = Pic
    MsgBox Pic.Name
    MsgBox TypeName(Pic)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, x) = Pic '(Doesn't work)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, x) = picObject '(Doesn't work)
    x = x + 1
Next Pic
```

But the point of making the active cell a picture doesn't work - I don't know how to insert each retrieved image into cells.

Comment: Just saw that you might be revisiting your old questions and noticed that you haven't accepted any answers to any of your questions. Thought I'd leave you a link to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) in case you weren't aware of either the existence of, or importance of, answer acceptance.

Comment: Incorrect. I hit the 'Up' button on the response to my question. Am I also supposed to submit a comment as well?

Comment: No, a comment is neither required, nor expected. If you click the words "this post" in my previous comment, you'll see what I actually meant. To accept an answer, you need to click on the check mark below the "Down" button  to toggle it from hollow (grey) to green. Accepting an answer is important as it informs others that the problem has been solved. Hitting the up button is *upvoting* an answer. You do this for any answers that were useful/helpful/correct. You can only accept a *single* answer, but you can upvote any/all answers, including the accepted one.

Comment: Also, I'm not going to get into an editing war with you, but the reason I changed the title was that it was (and now, still is) incorrect and doesn't reflect the actual problem. You already *know* how to extract a `Picture` object from an `ArrayList`, as your second code block shows. What you don't know how to do is *move* the picture so it looks like it's in the specified cell. Note that, in the first code block, the pictures don't actually get physically moved into the `ArrayList` - ***references*** to the `Picture` objects are added instead. **The pictures remain exactly where they are**…

Comment: **on the sheet.** Similarly, when you "extract" the picture objects from the `ArrayList` you make a *copy* of the *reference*. **The pictures are still exactly where they were on the sheet.** To actually move the pictures, you change their *position* properties, `Left` and `Top`.

Comment: Yes ok, I understand re: accepting the answer, and will endevour to do so in the future. As for the nature of the question, it is exactly as I told. Msgbox tells me the contents of the ArrayList. This has nothing to do with making use of that information. The second block of code doesn't work. I even said so twice. Making an activecell the value of ArrayList(x) didn't work. I know how to move a picture. I don't want to merely move the pictures from one place to another. I want to place the Array contents as needed, and as often as needed. I dont/ didnt know how to extract it from an arraylist.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the picture's ***location*** to that of the target cell. Like so:

```
Pic.Left = ActiveCell.Offset(0, x).Left
Pic.Top = ActiveCell.Offset(0, x).Top
```

Note that in Excel, you can't actually insert pictures *into* cells. Pictures "float" above the worksheet.

You can, however, "link" the picture to the cells it's floating over so that it moves and resizes with the cells, thus *behaving* as if it's inside them.